# How to get web hook data with GitHub using PHP

Tags: php, git, github, webhooks

I've setup a GitHub webhook with a secret and selected application/x-www-form-urlencoded for the content type.

I tried to search around but there does not seem to be much info on how to use the post data, such as what does GitHub include in the POST request,  can I just do:

`$_POST["secret"]` or is there more to it than that? I know I could test this myself but with the way I setup the webhook its hard to see the output and more of a pain to do a var_dump() for POST.

So basically my question is what is the POST layout when GitHub sends a POST request, because I am looking to validate which branch was pushed and validate the secret as well.

Comment: Have you checked [the documentation](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/)?

Comment: @rickdenhaan the github docs does not say how to read that header (or any header) in PHP. and as usual, php does some fuckery, in this case, to the header name. uppercasing it, and replacing `-` with `_` (and god knows what else), so the final PHP name is actually `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_HUB_SIGNATURE']`

Comment: @hugyt7 btw you might find this interesting, this is how i use webhooks to keep a development website always up-to-date with the main repo; https://pastebin.com/JcUevvP3

Comment: The docs do say the following: "The `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content type will send the JSON payload as a form parameter called "payload"." So there should be a JSON string in `$_POST['payload']`

Answer (score 0):

seems it is translated by PHP as `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_HUB_SIGNATURE']`

- but when in doubt as to how PHP will name a header, set up a page with `<?php phpinfo(~0);` , and run curl with the url like `curl http://ratma.net/phpinfo.php --header "X-Hub-Signature: test" -v 2>&1 | grep -i test` , and you should see what the header is called. in this case, i got
  `<tr><td class="e">$_SERVER['HTTP_X_HUB_SIGNATURE']</td><td class="v">test</td></tr>`

Comment: Accessing HTTP headers using `$_SERVER` is a workaround. If you're running on Apache, you should be using [apache_request_headers()](https://secure.php.net/apache_request_headers). (or its alias `getallheaders()`) This should return an array containing a key called `X-Hub-Signature`.